# More than one result for coordinates from PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I'm using a modified version of [pyris](https://github.com/garaud/pyris) to get IRIS codes from France.  I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database based on a shapefile.

My problem is, when I query the result for a coordinate, I get more than one result. That should not. An IRIS code should be unique for one result.

For example:

```
SELECT
iris ,nom_com ,depcom ,nom_iris ,dcomiris ,typ_iris 
FROM geoiris 
WHERE geom && st_makepoint(4.808744, 45.980649);



iris |     nom_com     | depcom |    nom_iris     | dcomiris  | typ_iris 
------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-----------+----------
 0000 | ARS-SUR-FORMANS | 01021  | ARS-SUR-FORMANS | 010210000 | Z
 0000 | MISERIEUX       | 01250  | MISERIEUX       | 012500000 | Z
 0000 | SAINTE-EUPHEMIE | 01353  | SAINTE-EUPHEMIE | 013530000 | Z
(3 rows)
```

The second result is right, but the two others not. The others are areas next to the right one.

Is there something wrong with my query?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and shp2pgsql for the shapefile.

Comment: Projection of your IRIS geometries?

Comment: The "&&" operator is an envelope query. If you plot the point, you'll see it fits in all three shapes' envelopes.

Comment: Use ST_Intersects instead of && for accurate result.

Comment: Thanks all of u, @user30184 answer helped me, now it works: "SELECT iris,nom_com,depcom,nom_iris,dcomiris,typ_iris FROM geoiris WHERE ST_Intersects(geom,ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(%f, %f), 4326))"

Comment: FYI using && is not wrong but it has a bit different purpose. && selects candidate features fast by utilizing spatial index. For speed and accurate results use `&& AND ST_Intersects`.